# Neural Networks Weight Decay and Weight Sharing

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, data-mining

I am having trouble understanding the concepts of weight decay and weight sharing for ANN's. Would someone mind explaining these two things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weight **decay** is an alteration to backpropagation, seeking to avoid overfitting, in which weights are decreased by a small factor during each iteration. From Mitchell *Machine Learning*, p. 111:

> This is equivalent to modifying the definition of $E$ [error function] to include a penalty term corresponding to the total magnitude of the network weights. The motivation for this approach is to keep weight values small, to bias learning against complex decision surfaces.

Weight **sharing** is when different units in the network literally share the same weights: They use identical values, "usually to enforce some constraint known in advance to the human designer." (Ibid. p. 118)